# How to switch dependencies based on build profile

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to use a feature from a dependency when I build in release profile and I don't want to use any feature while testing/development.

For example, the dependency is normally defined as:

```
[depenencies.my_dep]
version = "*"
```

But when I build in release profile, I want it to be

```
[depenencies.my_dep]
version = "*"
features = [my_feature]
```

From the cargo documentation I can make out that this can be achieved only for platform targets. Is there a way to do it for profile based configuration?

Comment: Though not a perfect answer to your question,  there is something like `cfg(debug_assertions)` used in the source code of `debug_assert` macro that does conditional compilation based on debug and release modes. I'd used it sometime back after reading the post here https://users.rust-lang.org/t/conditional-compilation-for-debug-release/1098

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea... Why would you not want to release the same code you test?

Comment: I use a crate which does some decentralised network operation. So when we develop I use the mock network feature of the library for development and testing. And then connect to the actual network for final testing and release

Comment: Although it's not exactly what you're looking for, why not just do `default-features = ["my_feature"]` and while developing using `cargo`s flag `--no-default-features`?

Comment: A good example is the `no-slow-safety-checks` feature of Amethyst (technically Rendy). It would be nice to enable this feature for release builds, but not for debug builds
https://book.amethyst.rs/stable/appendices/c_feature_gates.html

Answer (score 7):

`cargo` does not support what you want directly. I see two options.

A. Use `dev-dependencies` which allow for tests to have different depends
   than debug/release. [dev-dependencies described](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-[dev-dependencies.*]-sections)

B. Have a Cargo-mock.toml and a Cargo-release.toml. Switch between them using `cargo build --manifest-path ./Cargo-<type>.toml`.