# Can I activate a dependency's feature only for debug profile?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have just started looking into the `Bevy` game engine for Rust. It has a feature called `dynamic`, which enables dynamic linking, to speed up compilation time during development. We are, however, advised to disable this when building for release.

Is there a way to tell Cargo to enable the `dynamic` feature for a debug build, but disable it for a release build? Or do I have to personally remember to change `bevy = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["dynamic"] }` to `bevy = "0.5.0"` in `Cargo.toml` before running `cargo build --release`?

Comment: What I did once was to create a feature in the exe itself, that adds the required release features: `[features] release = ["bevy/dynamic"]`, and then instead of `cargo build --release` I have a deployment script, or recently a [`xtask`](https://github.com/matklad/cargo-xtask).

Comment: I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403430/how-to-switch-dependencies-based-on-build-profile). I'd just do anything mentioned there and have a `Makefile` to `make release` and `make debug` respectively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Along the lines of Rodrigo's comment, can confirm the following seems to work well:

```
[dependencies]
bevy = { version = "0.5.0" }

[features]
default = ["fast-compile"]
fast-compile = ["bevy/dynamic"]
```

Then for development, simply: `cargo build`

And for release: `cargo build --release --no-default-features`

Comment: That is, at the very least, loads better than manually changing `Cargo.toml`. It's not optimal, as I still have to remember the flag in the first place. But it very much seems like the most ergonomic solution.